# How can we achieve a left join by using subquery in Cosmos DB?

Tags: sql, azure-cosmosdb

Here I am using the same document in left join as well:

```
select A.a,A.b,C.c
from Inventory A left join
     (select B.a as id,B.a*100 as c
      from Inventory B
      where condition1 and condition2
     ) as C
     on C.id
     on A.a
```

How could I achieve this without a left join in the above use-case?

Comment: Your query makes no sense even after I have formatted it.  Sample data, desired results, and an explanation of the logic would help.

Comment: fyi https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49368254/cosmosdb-join-sql-api

Answer (score 1):

Cosmos DB only support self-join by now.You can refer to this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-query-join).Left join is in Cosmos DB Development Team plan,and tentative start for H2 2020.You can track this feature [here](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/c6357afe-0e25-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f0858).

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that `on C.id on A.a` is a typo and is really meant to be `on C.id = A.a`:

```
select a.a, a.b, c.c
from inventory a 
left join 
(
  select b.a as id, b.a * 100 as c
  from inventory b
  where condition1 and condition2
) as c on c.id = a.a;
```

equals

```
select a.a, a.b, 
  (
    select b.a * 100
    from inventory b
    where condition1 and condition2
    and b.a = a.a
  ) as c
from inventory a;
```